# Negative number input help-how-to

Tags: c++

```
// ConsoleApplication6.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int getInput() {

    while (true) {

        std::cout << "Indtast fire point-tal mellem 0 og 100: ";

        int number = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        int number3 = 0;
        int number4 = 0;
        std::cin >> number;
        std::cin >> number2;
        std::cin >> number3;
        std::cin >> number4;
        int sum;
        sum = (number + number2 + number3 + number4) / 4;


        std::cout << "\n";

        if (std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cout << "Fejl, prøv igen!\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            continue;
        }

        if (std::cin.bad() || std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cout << "Ugyldigt input (fejl i input af tal).\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        if (sum < 0 || sum > 100) {
            std::cout << "Ugyldigt input, det skal være mellem 0 og 100!.\n";
            continue;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // unreachable
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    int sum = getInput();

    std::cout << "Gennemsnittet af antal point: ";
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    if (sum >= 90) {
        puts("Karakter: \n");
        puts("12");
    }
    else if (sum >= 80) {
        puts("Karakter: \n");
        puts("10");
    }
    else if (sum >= 70) {
        puts("Karakter: \n");
        puts("7");
    }
    else if (sum >= 60) {
        puts("Karakter: \n");
        puts("4");
    }
    else if (sum >= 50) {
        puts("Karakter: \n");
        puts("02");
    }
    else {
        puts("Karakter: \n");
        puts("00");
    }
}
```

Currently, my code processes negative inputs the same way as positive inputs. But I would like to implement an "if" that filters negative numbers and come back with an error and maybe also restart the loop. How would I do that?

getInput() retrieves 4 numeric inputs, with an error if letters are submitted as input and if the input isn't between 0-100 then it does the same.

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you tried to add a condition to check that all numbers are positive?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: currently you only check that `sum` is between 0 and 100, if you want to check the input then you need to check the input

Comment: Make a function that reads and returns one positive number and call it four times.

Comment: Also, if you refer to the average as "sum", you're going to make yourself very confused sooner or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a `inputPositive` function that reads the input and sets a boolean to `true` if the input number was negative:

```
void inputPositive(int& number, bool& negative) {
    std::cin >> number;
    if (number < 0) {
        negative = true;
    }
}
```

then you can call these functions for the 4 numbers. If negative flag is set we say `continue;` to return the start of the `while(true)`:

```
while (true) {

    std::cout << "Indtast fire point-tal mellem 0 og 100: ";

    bool negative = false;

    int number = 0;
    int number2 = 0;
    int number3 = 0;
    int number4 = 0;

    inputPositive(number, negative);
    inputPositive(number2, negative);
    inputPositive(number3, negative);
    inputPositive(number4, negative);

    if (negative) {
        std::cout << "Invalid. Input only positive numbers\n\n"; 
        continue;
    }

    //...
}
```

output:

```
Indtast fire point-tal mellem 0 og 100: 10 20 30 -40
Invalid. Input only positive numbers

Indtast fire point-tal mellem 0 og 100: 10 20 30 40

Gennemsnittet af antal point: 25
```

---

you should use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for your function. It will shorten your code length, and allows to use features like [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) which calculates the sum:

```
bool negative = false;

std::array<int, 4> numbers;
for (auto& i : numbers) {
    inputPositive(i, negative);
}
        
auto sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0) / numbers.size();
```